# Key Value Pair Comparison based on key only

Tags: c#, asp.net, keyvaluepair

Hello Guys Im stuck at something.I am creating a key value pair list something like this

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C2", 1));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C2", 2));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("A1", 4));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B1", 5));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B1", 6));
```

Now after adding the items.What i want is i want to sort the list according to the key. i have used this code to sort the above list

```
list.Sort(new KvpKeyComparer<string, int>());
```

The Output is something Like this

```
[A1, 4]
[B1, 5]
[B1, 6]
[C2, 1]
[C2, 2]
```

Now what i want is i want to compare the value of last key which is at index 4 i.e
   [c2,2]   to [C2,1] using an if condition.But i only want to compare c2 to c2 n not the whole pair [c2,2]   to [C2,1].based on that i will do some of my operations.thn after first comparison i will compare index 3 to index to i.e [c2,1] to [b1,6].Again the comparison should be between C2 and B1.i.e it should check in an if condition that if (C2=B1) ..i cannot achieve this..can anyone help me.i have been trying.im a newbiew so help me out

Comment: Homework? This doesn't sound like a sort from the description of "operations" being done in the middle of item-by-item comparisons

Comment: Obviously I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why are you doing the comparisons that you describe, and why can't you do the comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

     for (int i=0;i<list.Count-1;i++)
    {
       if (list[i].Value>list[i+1].Value)
        {         
          list2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(list[i].Key,list[i].Value)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much.It worked..One more query if u can answer.now it execute according to the logic part.i mean if the condition is satisfied.i want to add both the key and value to another key value pair list..how can i do that?

Answer (score -2):

A much easier option is to use LINQ to do the ordering:

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry i couldnt get it.